# Connect some points in plot base R

Tags: plot, line, point, radix

I want to connect some points (not all) in a scatterplot using plot function in base R.
In this dataset:

```
             X            Y
1   0.29932778  0.238057774
2   0.28401751 -0.002339008
3   0.09659869 -0.166738748
4  -0.14366057 -0.159493487
5  -0.30832867  0.003972387
6  -0.31993953  0.103418512
7  -0.30074406  0.201896676
8  -0.14272981 -0.041889234
9  -0.03191046 -0.125692016
10  0.10640495 -0.133728404
11  0.21041771 -0.029733632
12  0.25054646  0.112269180
```

I want to connect points from 1 to 7 and from 8 to 12. I don't want a connection between points 7 and 8.

In this code, I can connect all points but I don't know how to remove the line between 7 and 8.

```
data <- data

plot (data)
lines (data)
```

[image: Scatterplot]